# curl multi part form data upload path format

Tags: curl, form-data

I'm trying make a curl script that uploads a form, I successfully created an HTTP authentication header which is redacted from the code below. How can I modify the code to refer to the file which is on my computer at : C:/Program Files/SamBobley_bankstatement.pdf

Thanks in advance for the thought you put into reviewing and answering my question!

```
    --url https://api.ocrolus.com/v1/book/upload \
    --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
    --header 'Authorization: Basic [Authorization Code Here]' \
    --form 'pk=10399' \
    --form 'upload=@C:/Program Files/SamBobley_bankstatement.pdf
```